# SQL SELECT when child table contains zero rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have two tables:

```
Table A
employeeID (int)
employeeName (varchar)
employeeDOB (varchar)

Table B
employeeID (int)
holidaysUsed (int)
```

Table B is relational to Table A via `employeeID`. Table B can have zero or more rows linked to a single employeeID. I'd like to perform a SELECT on Table A but only retrieve rows in Table A when there are no corresponding records in table B.

I have a few ideas on this but I'd like to ensure I'm using the optimum query. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Additional Information**

Database platform: SQL Server 2008 R2

Typical returned dataset size 1000 records avg.

Comment: Is `employeeID` nullable in either of the tables?

Comment: No employeeID cannot be NULL in either table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE employeeID NOT IN (SELECT employeeID FROM B);`

Comment: One other way to do it would be `select a.* from a left join b on b.employeeID=a.employeeID where b.employeeID is null`. Could be faster by the way.